# VBA: get names of ranges from cell in 2 ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 named ranges which refer to the same cell, and only that cell. I want to be able to get the names of those ranges when that cell is the Target, but only 1 of them is returned.

Example:

Named range 'DATA_CELL' refers to cell A1.
Named range 'EVENT_CELL' refers to cell A1.

On detecting a click in cell A1, Target.Name.Name returns EVENT_CELL only.

If EVENT_CELL refers to more than one cell e.g. A1:A3, Target.Name.Name returns DATA_CELL.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can reliably get the name of both ranges which refer to the cell regardless of any other cells either of the ranges may refer to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, loops through each name on the current worksheet and only returns, as a message, those that are associated with the active cell

```
Sub Find_Names()

' Loop through all names in workbook.
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names

    ' Check to see if the name refers to the ActiveSheet.
    If InStr(1, n.RefersTo, ActiveSheet.Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        ' If name refers to ActiveSheet, then find the intersection of the
        ' named range and the ActiveCell.
        Set y = Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(n.RefersTo))

        ' Display a message box if the ActiveCell is in the named range.
        If Not y Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Cell contains name : " & n.Name

    End If

Next

' Display message when finished.
MsgBox "No More Names!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have said in my original post that I was using a search of all names in the workbook as a workaround!